# eclipse java - crashing on linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am currently using openSuSE with XFCE and I installed Eclipse through YAST. Ecipse is version 3.4.0 and usually it crashes for no reason but I have been able to recreate the error when I write the the '.' in `import java.io.*;` and the 'err' in `System.err.println();`.This is the error message eclipse emits:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0.v20130605-2000/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib64/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130521-0416/eclipse_1506.so
-startup /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1cd0022
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib64/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
```

`java -version` returns

java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (suse-8.18.1-x86_64)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)

Comment: seems like your content assistent is crashing. what happens, when you deactivate it? (window->preferences->java->...)

Comment: @desperateCoder Thanks this seems to have solved the problem. It's unfortunate as now I have to constanstantly have to look back at the javadocs. Is there a way to have the best of both worlds i.e. content assist + not crashing?

Comment: @desperateCode It seemed to have solved the problem for a while but it is repeatedly crashing again.

Comment: You could try reinstall eclipse. If this doesn't help, i'd try to get a standalone-bundle like this one: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR1/eclipse-java-kepler-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz . but i dont exactly know how to solve the crashing-problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the .log file to resolve the problem. It is located in the workspace/.metadata/.log . It will tell you why it is crashing and will give you the stacktrace of the issue.

Comment: I don't hava a .metadata file in the project folder. There is only .classpath(xml file), .project(xml file), .settings(folder), bin(folder), res(folder I made), src(folder).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try adding

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

to `eclipse.ini` file.